# Microsoft Shims with a WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, microsoft-fakes

I am attempting to follow [this example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Unit-Test-a-having-404c2a18) and leverage a shim to remove the external dependency on a WCF service call which is called from the method I am executing the unit test on.  Unlike the example, I generate my WCF client on the fly using code similar to this:

```
ChannelFactory<IReportBroker> factory = new ChannelFactory<IReportBroker>("ReportBrokerBasicHttpStreamed", new EndpointAddress(this.CurrentSecurityZoneConfigurationManager.ConfigurationSettings[Constants.ConfigurationKeys.ReportBrokerServiceUrl]));
IReportBroker proxy = factory.CreateChannel();
proxy.Execute(requestMessage))
```

How do I adapt that example to shim the proxy returned back by the CreateChannel method?  I am assuming that in the ShimWCFService class, I need to add something like....

```
ShimChannelFactory<TService>.AllInstances.CreateChannel = (var1) => { return [instance of a mock object]};
```

However, I am unsure of how to associate a mock object of `<TService>` with that shim as the return value.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shim the factory for every type parameter. Assume you have the three Service contracts 'IService0' 'IService1' and 'IService2'.

Then you need to setup the shims like this:

```
ShimChannelFactory<IService0>.AllInstances.CreateChannel = (_) => { return new Service0Mock(); }
ShimChannelFactory<IService1>.AllInstances.CreateChannel = (_) => { return new Service1Mock(); }
ShimChannelFactory<IService2>.AllInstances.CreateChannel = (_) => { return new Service2Mock(); }
```